# Perl6 one liner execution. How is the topic updated?

Tags: command-line, raku

Executing the one liner to process CSV a line at a time from stdin:

```
perl6 -ne 'my @a; $_.split(",").kv.map: {@a[$^k]+=$^v}; say @a; ENTER {say "ENTER"}; BEGIN {say "BEGIN"}; LEAVE {say "LEAVE"}; END {say "END"}';
```

Typing in:

```
1,1
1,1
^D
```

Gives the following output:

```
BEGIN
ENTER
1,1
[1 1]
1,1
[2 2]
LEAVE
END
```

Here we can see that the one liner is not a block executed multiple times as the ENTER and LEAVE phaser are only executed once.

This makes sense as the variable @a is accumulating. If the one liner was a block the value of @a would be reset each time.

My question is how does the topic variable $_ get updated? The topic variable is a Str (at least that's what $_.^name says). How does its value update without re-entering the block?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you add `-n` it adds a `for` loop around your code.

You think it adds one like this:

```perl6
for lines() {
  # Your code here
}
```

The compiler just adds the abstract syntax tree nodes for looping without actually adding a block.

```perl6
(
   # Your code here
) for lines()
```

(It could potentially be construed as a bug.)

To get it to work like the first one:

```perl6
(             # -n adds this

  -> $_ {     # <-- add this

              # Your code here

  }( $_ )     # <-- add this

) for lines() # -n adds this
```

I tried just adding a bare block, but the way the compiler adds the loop causes that to not work.

---

In general `ENTER` and `LEAVE` are scoped to a block `{}`, but they are also scoped to the “*file*” if there isn't a block.

```perl6
ENTER say 'ENTER file';
LEAVE say 'LEAVE file';
{
  ENTER say '  ENTER block';
  LEAVE say '  LEAVE block';
}
```

```
ENTER file
  ENTER block
  LEAVE block
LEAVE file
```

Since there is no block in your code, everything is scoped to the “*file*”.

Comment: Hmm.. the statement `my @a;` is still redeclaring the @a variable so there is no accumulation happening in my testing of your suggestion. So this means it is still executed as a block? The `my @a` is persistent across input lines in the one liner program. This is the difference I can't understand. I'm testing on Rakudo 2018.12 if that makes any difference.

Comment: @RubenWesterberg I use the absolute latest version of Rakudo. I update daily. There were some optimizations that may cause some differences.

Comment: I finally got a chance to look at this again. I can replicate the command line behaviour now, using the postfix form of the 'for' statement as you suggested @BradGilbert.  `(#code goes here) for lines();` The block phasers don't execute as it isn't a block. Interestingly if I assign an initial value to the @a variable when declared, the accumulation again stops. i.e `my @a=(0,0);` vs `my @a;`.

Comment: @RubenWesterberg `my @a = 0,0` is effectively two separate things. A declaration `my @a` and an assignment `= 0,0`. The declaration adds the variable to the symbol table of the given scope at compile-time. The assignment is code that is run each time that line is reached.

Comment: *"it could be potentially construed as a bug."* Do you think this is a bug?

Comment: @jubilatious1 If I myself considered it a bug, I would have said so. I am also not convinced that it isn't. So if you came away from reading that sentence that I was unsure of it being a bug, well that was the correct take away.

Comment: @BradGilbert thank you for the favor of a reply. Well it's two years later...you may have had a change of opinion in the intervening period, and/or a Github issue may have been opened on this particular behavior.

Answer (score 3):

The `-n` [command line argument](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/wiki/Running-rakudo-from-the-command-line) puts a loop around your program,

```
for $*ARGFILES.lines {
    # Program block given on command line
}
```

whereas the [program execution phasers](https://docs.perl6.org/language/phasers#Program_execution_phasers) you used (`BEGIN` and `END`), are [run once](https://docs.perl6.org/language/phasers#Program_execution_phasers) either at compile time or after the program block has finished, so they will not be part of the loop at run time.

The [ENTER](https://docs.perl6.org/language/phasers#Block_phasers) block phaser will run at every block entry time, whereas the 
the [LEAVE](https://docs.perl6.org/language/phasers#Block_phasers) block phaser will run at every block exit time. So these phasers will be run for each line read in the `for` loop.

Comment: The ENTER and LEAVE Phasers are executed each time for a block. Running a for statement around the one-liner parts causes the phasers to run for each line as is the declaration of the variable @a. <br/> `for $*ARGFILES.lines {
     my @a;
 .split(",").kv.map: {say $^v;@a[$^k]+=$v};
 say @a;
 ENTER {say "ENTER"}; BEGIN {say "BEGIN"}; LEAVE {say "LEAVE"}; END {say "END"};
}`<br/> Running with the same input as originally gives: `BEGIN
1,1
ENTER
1
1
[1 1]
LEAVE
1,1
ENTER
1
1
[1 1]
LEAVE
END`

Comment: First time for everything :)  . The only way I can make sense of it currently is if the `my @a` is actually made into `state @a` ,  which is only initialised once the first time the block is executed. Thus for next execution the variable already exists and the accumulation part works.

Comment: I see now that I missed an important part of you question: when reading arguments from STDIN, the  `ENTER` and `LEAVE` seem *not* to be called for each line read, as you also observe.. I missed this part since I was testing this with input from file like this `perl6 test.p6 file.csv`, and in this case the phasers was called for each line.. I am not sure what is going on here, maybe the `ENTER` and `LEAVE` phasers are associated with a block outside the `for` loop somehow?

Answer (score 1):

**Update -- Rakudo 2020.10**

Running your original accumulator code (using the `-ne` linewise flag) gives the following result. Note how the word "final" appears in every line:

```perl6
~$ perl6 -ne 'my @a; $_.split(",").kv.map: {@a[$^k]+=$^v}; say @a, " final"; ENTER {say "ENTER"}; BEGIN {say "BEGIN"}; LEAVE {say "LEAVE"}; END {say "END"};' drclaw.txt
BEGIN
ENTER
[1 1] final
[2 3] final
[3 6] final
LEAVE
END
```

Below, running essentially duplicate scripts back-to-back with the `-ne` flag gives an interesting result. `BEGIN`, `ENTER`,`LEAVE`, and `END` show up in the exact same location, duplicated on the order of once-per-call:

```perl6
~$ perl6 -ne 'my @a; .split(",").kv.map: {@a[$^k]+=$^v}; say @a, " final_a";  ENTER {say "ENTER"}; BEGIN {say "BEGIN"}; LEAVE {say "LEAVE"}; END {say "END"};  my @b; .split(",").kv.map: {@b[$^k]+=$^v}; say @b, " final_b"; ENTER {say "ENTER"}; BEGIN {say "BEGIN"}; LEAVE {say "LEAVE"}; END {say "END"};' drclaw.txt
BEGIN
BEGIN
ENTER
ENTER
[1 1] final_a
[1 1] final_b
[2 3] final_a
[2 3] final_b
[3 6] final_a
[3 6] final_b
LEAVE
LEAVE
END
END
```

However, removing the `-ne` flag below lets you run a `for lines() {...}` loop within the Raku code itself (single script, not duplicated back-to-back). This result seems more in line with what you were expecting:

```perl6
~$ perl6 -e 'my @a; for lines() {.split(",").kv.map: {@a[$^k]+=$^v};}; say @a, " final"; ENTER {say "ENTER"}; BEGIN {say "BEGIN"}; LEAVE {say "LEAVE"}; END {say "END"};' drclaw.txt
BEGIN
ENTER
[3 6] final
LEAVE
END
```

I think the short answer to your questions is that Phasers respect Block/Loop semantics, but are limited script-wise as to how many times they will report back to the implementer (apparently only once per call). But the ultimate difference is that the return to the user is ***linewise*** for the `-ne` command line flag, as compared to an internal `for lines() {...}` loop *sans* the `-ne` command line flag.

Finally, you can always force the reloading of the `$_` topic variable with the `andthen` infix operator. Maybe this is what you were looking for all along:

```perl6
~$ perl6 -e 'my @a; for lines() {.split(",").kv.map: {@a[$^k]+=$^v} andthen $_.say }; say @a, " final"; ENTER {say "ENTER"}; BEGIN {say "BEGIN"}; LEAVE {say "LEAVE"}; END {say "END"};' drclaw.txt
BEGIN
ENTER
(1 1)
(2 3)
(3 6)
[3 6] final
LEAVE
END
```

[Test file under analysis, below].

```perl6
~$ cat drclaw.txt
1,1
1,2
1,3
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-andthen